# Can't build XMPPFramework for iOS 6

Tags: ios, xcode, xmppframework

I have some unsolved problems when i am using XMPPFramework ...

At first I downloaded it on (https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework)

as i know, it is the lastest version which can be used in iOS6...

Second, I attached source-code on my program (Authentication,Categories,Core,Extensions,Utilities,Vendor).

Third, I changed some paths
User Header Search Paths = /usr/include/libxml2
Other Linker Flags = -lxml2

but, result is "Lexical or Preprocessor issus 'libxml/tree.h' file not found"

what should i do? if i was change from libxml to libxml2 ... i cannot another .h files which are prohibited...

plz help me and thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `/usr/include/libxml2` to **Header Search Paths**, not **User Header Search Paths**.

Comment: Thanks for your comment... I did it and succeeded~!

Comment: If this solved your problem, please click the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: sorry, but which button i can click...?

Comment: if i click upper triangle shape button, vote up requires 15 reputation message is pop up...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.  My XMPPFramework folder was a sibling to my iOS project.  In my iOS project, I had created an Xcode group folder, then dragged the KissXML folder content into that project folder (group), without copying files.

The solution was to delete the group, drag the KissXML folder into the project and copy them into the project.  So now, on disk, my KissXML files exist under my project folder.  This isn't what I want, but it now compiles fine.